# gostaria de saber como eu faço pra remover uma div class com js

Tags: javascript, html, css

gostaria de saber como eu faço pra remover um certo elemento do meu site com js
já tentei varias coisas.
Consigo remover por id. mas class eu não sei e já procurei em vários lugares.

```
var node = document.getElementById("formCalcularCep");
if (node.parentNode) {
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

gostaria de remover isso porque o template do meu site e pago, e não consigo ter acesso total do código, e não quero pagar a empresa pra fazer essa remoção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: basicamente a mesma coisa, mas um seletor por id (`getElementById`) retorna um único elemento, um seletor por classe vai retornar várias, uma vez que a mesma classe pode ser utilizada por vários elementos, então precisa outra característica para selecionar o elemento certo. Por exemplo, se fosse o primeiro elemento encontrado, poderia fazer algo como `var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("nome-da-class"); divs[0].remove();`

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo!

Answer (score -4):

já procurou ocultar o elemento pela classe utilizando JQuery?
Segue um exemplo:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.classe').hide();
   });
```